# Recommendation book to learn how computers work at a transistor level

Tags: reference-request, computer-architecture

I would like to know your book recommendations / popular books to learn how computers perform operations, store memory, process your mouse input to open a program for example (maybe not that complicated) at transistor / logic gate level

Comment: like this guy explains in a computerphile video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XETZoRYdtkw

Comment: *The Elements of Computing Systems* by Nisan & Schocken is popular.

Comment: I'll check it out :)

Comment: The "best" book is subjective; everyone will have their own opinion, all equally valid, so the question basically devolves to a popularity poll.  Such recommendation questions are not suitable for this site.  See http://cs.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask.

Comment: When you say "best book" you are indeed asking for their recommendation based on what they have read. Of course there is not a best book on anything! Next time i'll be more specific with my question.

Comment: Of interest: [Building an 8-bit breadboard computer!](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLowKtXNTBypGqImE405J2565dvjafglHU) by Ben Eater - A long series of YouTube videos on building a working 8-bit computer using digital logic chips. The computer can even run a simple high-level program after it is compiled into the machine opcodes. It's addicting.